# What does the prefix of the raw transaction encoding of an exported Electrum transaction file (.txn) mean?

Tags: transactions, electrum, bip32-hd-wallets

I have exported a testnet transaction into a .txn file:

```
{
    "hex": "45505446ff0002000000000101c6be24d86ab1ae5b54e7e7905b...",
    "complete": false,
    "final": false
}
```

However, as explained in this [article](https://medium.com/coinmonks/bitcoin-p2pkh-transaction-breakdown-bb663034d6df), a raw transaction string starts with version number and:

> The version number is four bytes long and is expressed as a hexadecimal value in little endian format.
>
> There are two version types. Version 01 indicates that there is no relative time lock. Version 02 indicates that there may be a relative time lock.

So this hex is not a qualified raw transaction encoding, due to the prefix

```
45505446ff00
```

The version number comes after this prefix:

```
02000000
```

So I was wondering, what is the function of this prefix that Electrum adds to the raw transaction string? And is it always the same length? Because I need to automatically splice it off in order to get a valid raw transaction string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It stands for:

`45505446` - EPTF - Electrum Partial Transaction Format
`ff` - Separator
`00` - EPTF Version - This is currently always 0.

You can verify this quickly by running a python interpreter.

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> b'EPTF\xff'.hex()
'45505446ff'
```